# Curl on AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have written a simple aws lambda function with Java:

My handler looks like this

```
public class HelloAWS implements RequestHandler<Map<String,String>, Object>{

@Override
public Object handleRequest(Map<String,String> i, Context cntxt) {
        String input = i.values().toString();
        return "Hello World via Lambda and Java!" + input;
}
```

The output of the AWS dashboard test looks like I expect it to look like:
"Hello World via Lambda and Java![value1, value2, value3]"

I'm trying to reproduce this test result with Ubuntu curl:

```
curl "https://myUrl.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/" -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"key1": "value1"}'
```

This yields an error:

```
An error occurred during JSON parsing: java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred during JSON parsing
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 84] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["headers"])
    at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.serialization.factories.JacksonFactory$InternalSerializer.fromJson(JacksonFactory.java:184)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 84] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["headers"])
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1445)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1219)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1129)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:63)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:10)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:527)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1719)
    at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1228)
    at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.serialization.factories.JacksonFactory$InternalSerializer.fromJson(JacksonFactory.java:182)
```

```
An error occurred during JSON parsing: java.lang.RuntimeException java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred during JSON parsing Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 84] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["headers"]) at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.serialization.factories.JacksonFactory$InternalSerializer.fromJson(JacksonFactory.java:184) Caused by: com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 84] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["headers"]) at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1445) at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1219) at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1129) at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:63) at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:10) at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:527) at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364) at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29) at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1719) at com.amazonaws.lambda.thirdparty.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1228) at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.serialization.factories.JacksonFactory$InternalSerializer.fromJson(JacksonFactory.java:182)
```

I found multiple sources indicating that I should be able to curl my service like this:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-lambda-function-urls-built-in-https-endpoints-for-single-function-microservices/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html

Why is Java treating my dashboard tests and my curl requests differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can use API gateway to configure your Lambda function so you can invoke it via CURL. Once you configure API Gateway, you can invoke a Lambda function built by using the Java Lambda run-time API with a command like:

```
curl -XGET "https://xxxxqjko1o3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/cronstage/employee"
```

Here is a Java example that walks you through this process. The Lambda function  created in this example also invokes AWS Services -- such as Amazon DynamoDB.

[Using Amazon API Gateway to invoke Lambda functions](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_apigateway)

**Update**

I just tested that and it worked fine. My Lambda function was invoked using this Curl command.

[image]

With respect to invoking a standalone Lambda function without using API Gateway, see this new article that may help  here:

[Announcing AWS Lambda Function URLs: Built-in HTTPS Endpoints for Single-Function Microservices](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-lambda-function-urls-built-in-https-endpoints-for-single-function-microservices/)

Confirmed - i followed that new article and it gives you an URL you can use to invoke via CURL without API Gateway....

[image]

When deploying your JAR (Lambda function) - make sure you choose this option:

[image]

Comment: But the OP is using a Lambda function URL, not API Gateway, and the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html#urls-invocation-basics) appear to suggest that exactly this use case is supported.

Comment: I will look into this. These docs state api gateway is used for this purpose too -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html

Comment: Well yes you can use API Gateway in front of Lambda, but the whole point of function URLs is that you don't need API Gateway.

Comment: It works in Java --  just confirmed

Comment: I believe your example uses a different interface and not handleRequest(Map<String,String> i, Context cntxt) - my question was why the dashboard test is treated differently than the curl - it obviously works when working with handleRequest(Object i, Context cntxt)

Comment: @MichailOstrowski, did you ever figure this out? I'm getting the same error, and yours is one of the few instances of it on the Internet!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloAWS implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayV2HTTPEvent, APIGatewayV2HTTPResponse> {

  @Override
  public APIGatewayV2HTTPResponse handleRequest(APIGatewayV2HTTPEvent request, Context context) {
    return null;
  }
```